# Can I access an SVN repository and its log by disk only and not using a server?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Is this possible?

Let me explain what I mean.  I have migrated from svn to hg but every once in a while need to use an old svn repository's history to figure out some issues.  I don't want to have to install and run VisualSVN (I run on Windows) to do this.  I have a backup of the repository via svnadmin dump.  I would like to be able to pull up "svn log" and look at diffs, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `file://` protocol schema to point to a local repository instead.

http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-repository.html#tsvn-repository-local-access

Comment: This points to the repository and not my working copy, correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the `file://` protocol to access your SVN repository.